# Pass CMake flags to VS Codes "tasks"?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, build, devops

So I have a `CMakeLists.txt` that works well and the solution runs in debug.

The tasks associated with VS Code (build active file, etc) call GCC ignoring the `CMakeLists.txt`. This is undesired because CMake sets required flags like the C++ standard version.

Anybody know how to pipe CMake into `tasks.json`?

For the default tasks look like:

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++-9 build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++-9",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Generated task by Debugger"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: cpp build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/cpp",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "/usr/bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/cpp"
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `call a version of GCC that ignores CMakeLists.txt`? gcc does not care about your `CMakeList.txt` ever. You need to run cmake for that.

Comment: another case of `"type": "cppbuild"`, `cppbuild` is not a valid value for `type`, where is the `cppbuild` example

Comment: if you use CMake, call `make` to build your program **NOT** `g++`. Don't call `cmake` for every build